# Finding the first date between multiple entries // PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My co-worker has run into an issue finding the amount of days between 2 different entries on a database.

In this database , there can be multiple entires with the same RegNumber , however sometimes the entries are on separate dates.

We would need to fetch the first date (TxrDate) for each RegNr and add it to the "FirstInvDate" column on each line.

Please see the below sample data:
[image]

And the below is what he has tried:

[image]

Does anyone know if there is an easier way to do this or a specific formula to follow ?

Answer (score 1):

To create a new table use:

```
FistInvDate = 
var __currRegNumber  = 'Table'[RegNumber]

return
calculate( min( table[yourDate]), filter(ALL('table'), __currRegNumber  = 'Table'[RegNumber]))
```